# WebClient.DownloadFileAsync Method : How to retrieve the Object?

Tags: c#, multithreading, webclient

I am trying to downaload file asynchronously from the server and i am useing weblcient for this purpose . While downloading the file Asyschromously , i am sending file( isntance of class file library) in the DownloadFileAsync( Uri address, string fileName, Object) method user-token )  but i am failing to retrieve the object i sent in this from method whihc invoked after download completed. here is the code details

> public void DownloadFileAsync(
>       Uri address,
>       string fileName,
>       Object userToken
>   )

and MSDN says **> userToken**

Type: System.Object
A user-defined object that is passed to the method invoked when the asynchronous operation completes.

actually , i am passing the file name in the calling :

```
wc.DownloadFileAsync(uri, file.StorePath,file);
```

and my download complete method is

```
void wc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var file = (FileLibrary)sender;
            this.DownloadedFileName = file.FileId;

        }
```

Error is :
**Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.WebClient' to type FileLibrary'.**

Accorrding to my understanding of above description, the object should be cast to 
**filelibrary** easily becouse the file name i sent in the calling of the same type.  why i am getting error 
or is there any other method to retrieve the sent Object:userToken

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The object you sent should be accessible via [e.UserState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.userstate.aspx) property

try this

`var file = (FileLibrary) e.UserState`